# THttprio onBeforeExecute changing the soapRequest

Tags: delphi, wsdl, delphi-2009

I've imported some wsdl for a project.
i want to change the SoapRequest on HttpRio onBeforeExecute event, but
as i changed the request, im getting some errors how can i change the request xml file
with stringReplace function on this event.

i've tried to change the size of stream, i ve changed the encoding etc. but anyway it didnt work.

example

```
procedure TForm1.RiomBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
  sTmp                                  : TStringList;

begin

  sTmp:=TStringList.Create;
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  sTmp.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  sTmp.Text := StringReplace(sTmp.Text,'blablaa','bla',[RfReplaceAll]);
  sTmp.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);
  // blaa blaa...
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.RiomBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
  sTmp                                  : TStringList;

begin

  sTmp:=TStringList.Create;
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  sTmp.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  sTmp.Text := StringReplace(sTmp.Text,'blablaa','bla',[RfReplaceAll]);
   **SOAPRequest.Postion:=0**;// i forget this here, as i write the code that worked
  sTmp.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);
  // blaa blaa...
end;
```

Comment: Yep! That'll do it. BTW, I use this approach too, to fix broken namespaces. This is also a great place to dump your SOAPRequest to a log file.

Answer (score 5):

Possible enhancement...   I found, with my situation (and this was in the soap response, btw, in case it matters), that if the resulting request is shorter than the original (and in your case it is), there was crud left over when the new string is written back out to the stream.
ex:

```
original: <blablaa some stuff>
intended: <bla some stuff>
actual:   <bla some stuff>uff>
```

Fix:

SOAPRequest.Postion:=0;// i forget this here, as i write the code that worked
**SOAPRequest.size := length(sTmp.Text);  // Important - set new length before saving.**
sTmp.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);