# How do I get the namespaces right when using a Transaction Exchange Server Web service?

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-7

I am trying to consume a [TxServer web service](http://207.150.244.30:9000/txserver/1?wsdl), but I'm getting the error response

> Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri: "http://txserver.sut.softekpr.com/1", local:"transaction")`. Expected elements are`<{}transaction>`.

I found out the XML that Delphi generates does not work with the service,
but if I add `xmlns=""` to the transaction tag, it works.
Can anyone help me to add `xmlns=""` to the transaction tag?
I'd like to have: `<transaction xmlns="">`.

BTW I tried changing: `InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(TxServer), ioDocument);` to all the io.. Options, but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <requestIVULoto xmlns="http://txserver.sut.softekpr.com/1">
      <transaction>
        <merchantId>00000000000</merchantId>
        <municipalTax>.01</municipalTax>
        <stateTax>.06</stateTax>
        <subTotal>1</subTotal>
        <tenderType>CASH</tenderType>
        <terminalId>POS02</terminalId>
        <terminalPassword/>
        <total>1.07</total>
        <txDate>2011-05-05T10:02:17.708Z</txDate>
        <txType>SALE</txType>
      </transaction>
    </requestIVULoto>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: @daemon_x, why did you replace "consume" with "implement" in your edit?

Comment: @Cosmin - because in Czech `consume` means also `destroy` and I hope OP don't wanna destroy that WS and in the other meanings it sounds like something to eat for me :)

Comment: In English, @Daemon, *consume* means *use* — in terms of computer services, it's the opposite of *publish*, and thus also the opposite of *implement*. (It can also mean *eat*, but we can reasonably assume that's not what this person is trying to do to the Web service.)

Comment: I meaned implement client side of the WS. But anyway there's something wrong with `<terminalPassword>` tag.

Comment: The <terminalPassword> tag is correct, what's wrong with it is the <transaction> tag, it should be <transaction xmlns="">, I just don't know how to fix it... Please help!

Comment: I can simulate it, but have no idea how to fix it :(

Answer (score 3):

`RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(InstitutionCode, #0, 'InstitutionCode');`

where `InstitutionCode` is some node name, `#0` empty char, simply empty string '' not working it is replaced by generated name.

It can be problem with widestring, but you can use TXSString instead

Answer (score 2):

Use an OnBeforePost event on the RIO object, and simply edit the outgoing string.  It's dirty, but it works.

```
procedure TMyHandler.RIO_BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; var SOAPRequest: WideString);
begin
  SOAPRequest := StringReplace(SOAPRequest,'<transaction>','<transaction xmlns="">',[]);
end;
```

Here is an example of hooking the RIO via the GUI way:
http://www.onlinedelphitraining.com/newsletters/webservices.htm

Here is discussion on doing it in code:
[THttprio onBeforeExecute changing the soapRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814850/thttprio-onbeforeexecute-changing-the-soaprequest)

Comment: ... actually, the D in RAD stands for 'dirty' ;)

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but where exactly do i insert this code? I do not have a component called RIO, and thank you very much for your time.....

Comment: Got it Chris, its making the change to <transaction xmlns="">, because I see the change with ShowMessage(SOAPRequest); but when it sends it to soapUI its changes it back to <transaction> Any suggestions?

Comment: Should be working... SOAPRequest should be going out on the wire as assigned. You can assign:   SOAPRequest := 'foo'; 
and that should show up in SoapUI (I assume you're using a SOAPUi Mockservice?)

Comment: Hmm... Delphi7.... maybe it's not really a VAR back in D7?  You may be able to use the RIO_OnBeforePost, but it's more involved.

Comment: Hey Chris, Thanks to you I got the web service to work! You are too kind, thank you very much for your time....

Answer (score 1):

Then try to use `THTTPRIO` component, if you have it in your Delphi distribution and try to pass it into the `GetTxServer` method call.

```
...
var MyTxServer: TxServer;
begin
  MyTxServer := GetTxServer(True, '', HTTPRIO1); // HTTPRIO1 is your component
end;
```

And as Chris mentioned before you can change the request in [OnBeforeExecute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Rio.TRIO.OnBeforeExecute) event (of that `HTTPRIO` component); I have D2009 so you will probably have different parameters if you have it at all.

```
procedure TForm10.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string;
  SOAPRequest: TStream);
var MyStringList: TStringList;

begin
  MyStringList := TStringList.Create;
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  MyStringList.LoadFromStream(SOAPRequest);
  MyStringList.Text := StringReplace(MyStringList.Text, '<transaction>', '<transaction xmlns="">', [RfReplaceAll]);
  SOAPRequest.Position := 0;
  MyStringList.SaveToStream(SOAPRequest);
end;
```