# My own SOAP code?

Tags: xml, delphi, post, soap, native

D6 prof.

We must use a SOAP XML service.
I tried to import wsdl, and use the interface generated by Delphi, but it is failed.

And: as I see I must provide username and password in an XML section, but I don't know how to do with this automatic interface...

I determined that I provide the XML by hand.
It is not problem, the problem is how to post into server...
The wsdl import knows how to call the server. It is know the url, port, etc.

I want to write my own code. As I think SOAP calls are uses "Post" method what I can do easily.
But what parameter is needed for post?
Which parameters is what read by SOAP server?

To understand what I talking about it, see this code (FParams : TStrings):

```
procedure TDDHTTPObject.Post;
var
    WinHttpReq : variant;
    posts : string;
begin
    Result := '';
    WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
    try
        posts := EncodeParamsToURL(FParams);
        URL := URL + '?' + posts;
        WinHttpReq.Open('POST', URL, false);
        WinHttpReq.Send();
        Result := WinHttpReq.ResponseText;
    finally
        WinHttpReq := 0;
    end;
end;
```

For example:

```
Params['data'] = xmlstring;
```

or

```
Params['soap'] = xmlstring;
```

Do you know something about it?

Comment: I recomment to use Indy or Synapse as they have good support for HTTP POST requests (and more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use .NET as your web server you can see the Methods and raw XML when you browse to the WS URL ie:
http://yourdomain.com/ws/ApplicationWebService.asmx

the XML is available for both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2
and it may look like this (SOAP 1.1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <UserIdentificationHeader xmlns="http://yourdomain.com/ws">
      <UserAgent>string</UserAgent>
      <UserToken>string</UserToken>
    </UserIdentificationHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <MyTestMethod xmlns="http://yourdomain.com/ws" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Next I use "MSXML2.XMLHTTP" like this:

```
var
  mhttp: OleVariant;

URL := 'http://yourdomain.com/ws/ApplicationWebService.asmx';
mhttp := CreateOleObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
mhttp.Open('POST', URL, False);  // False=synchronously
mhttp.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', APP_WS_USER_AGENT); // optional
mhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8');
mhttp.setRequestHeader('SoapAction', 'http://yourdomain.com/ws/' + 'MyTestMethod');

mhttp.send(TheSOAPXML);

if mhttp.Status = 202 then ShowMessage('ACCEPTED OK!');
```

Answer (score 3):

Instantiate your own THttpRio component and pass it in to the web service call. Use the THttpRio.BeforeExecute event to modify the SOAPRequest stream before it gets sent to the service. Lots of examples out there but look at [THttprio onBeforeExecute changing the soapRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814850/thttprio-onbeforeexecute-changing-the-soaprequest) as one to get you going.

Comment: The main problem that I can import the wsdl, but the calling of the site is give 404 error, so the first that I must connect to it - maybe with other MS COM object.

Comment: Your original question didn't say anything about a 404 error. You asked how to pass in a username and password in the XML section. You might consider rewording your question so you get an answer to the problem. 404 indicates the resource isn't there. Perhaps the endpoint listed in the WSDL isn't correct so the default URL in the implementation of your unit is non-existent, resulting in a 404 error. Try using SoapUI to make your web service call. That will help narrow down your problem to either Delphi or the web service.